# How to set min value for input type time elements?

Tags: html, forms, validation, time

How set minimum and maximum values for `<input type="time">` elements in HTML5.

I need this because I want to restrict users from inserting non working hours of a day. The minimum value should not be less than 7 AM and maximum value should not be greater than 6 PM.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript is of course a better solution until there's more browser support.

```
<input type="time" min="07:00:00" max="18:00:00" />
```

should do the trick

https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/time

Comment: It is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you rather to use  ***javascript***.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checktimeval(){
  var timeval=*document.getElementById("theidofurinput").value*;
  if(!(timeval > 1 && timeval < 12)){
    document.getElementById("theidoferrorspan").innerHTML="Please enter time <7 a.m and >6 p.m";
  }
}
```

Then call this function ***onblur*** of the input element.